# Will I face problems if staying 91 days in the US visa-free?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

I am going in less then a month to the United States for a 3 month period. 
I already have an ESTA that's valid until the end of the year.

I already have my flight tickets, but I read somewhere that I am allowed to stay 90 days, but unfortunately I counted the days I am staying are 91.

Do you think I will have problems? My ticket its not refundable, so I really didn't want to pay for the excessive fees they charge for changing the dates.

Comment: Note that ESTA is, essentially, authorization to get on a plane headed towards the USA, so the duration of its validity doesn't really affect anything. It needs to be valid on the day you get on the plan but not for the whole of your trip.

Comment: @DavidRicherby This doesn't belong to the issue. but very important Point nonetheless!

Comment: Post the dates and times of your flights so we can check that your counting is correct according to the US legal interpretation.

Comment: Actual dates are irrelevant for this particular question, although can be useful for the OP. For the sake of this question you should assume that the number of days is indeed 91.

Comment: Talk to airlines and you should be able to reschedule your departure date.

Comment: Well,  with  the Orange Caligula  doing whatever BannonLooseCannon tells him to do, in all honesty nobody can predict whether you'll be allowed in or for how long.   Be careful.

Answer (score 54):

You have 3 options:

1. Rebook your return ticket / Buy an additional one-way return ticket (might be less expensive than re-booking a non-refundable ticket)
2. Get a visa (costs USD 160)
3. Overstay, be banned from entering without a visa ever again, and get a black mark in the US systems.

Personally I would go with option 1, but it's up to you.

Comment: Was just about to post this exact answer - that 1 day will end your Visa Waiver Program eligibility for ever, if the US notices it (and in this day and age, chances are they will notice it).

Comment: @Moo "Chances are"? Since she's exiting by air, they WILL, because all entries and exits by air and ship are electronically recorded

Comment: I never ever like to work in absolutes ;)

Comment: I contacted the airline and it's definitely MUCH cheeper to get the visa.. I will contact the embassy.. usually how many days you need to get one?

Comment: First you have to wait for an interview, and once it's approved, it's usually 3-5 working days for you to get the passport back. In what city in your nearest US embassy or consulate? I can check the waiting times for interviews

Comment: Berlin, I already applied for the interview, fingers crossed!

Comment: @sabine The current waiting time is 3 calendar days, and 1 calendar day after the interview, so you should have the visa within 4-5 calendar days. Keep in mind, they'll likely ask why you're not entering visa-free. Tell them as it is: you messed up your booking by one day and it would've been more expensive to modify the return ticket, and you should be fine

Comment: @sabine And lastly, the visa will be multiple-entry and valid for 10 years, so you can use it freely in the next 10 years - you'll usually be granted a 6-month stay on each entry

Comment: @sabine Someone made an important edit to 1. Check it as soon as you read this

Comment: @crazydre Good information, but - sometimes you can get a visa by mail, no interview, and the period is not necessarily ten years. I have been given a five-year visa, I have been given a 1-year visa. It seems to be up to the issuing officer and may depend on what you say at interview, the remaining validity in your passport, and other factors.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, say that you had a flight booked to leave on day 90, and the airplane delayed the flight to the next day so in essence you stayed for 91. If you were told to leave the airport to stay in a hotel overnight while waiting for the flight, would you be violating the VISA-free period?

Comment: @SGR You would have to send clear evidence of it to the CBP - preferably in person at the airport before departure.

Comment: @AdamEberbach B visas specifically are 10-year and multiple-entry by default for VWP nationals. Only in extraordinary circumstances will they be less

Comment: @sabine Have you filled out the DS-160 online? If not, it's here - make sure you select a B visa (second option in the list I think) and then B1/B2 https://ceac.state.gov/genniv/

Comment: @Coke not all VWP countries have 10 year B visa reciprocity.  Australians, for example, get 1 year visas, or, if they pay $25 extra, 5 year visas.

Comment: @phoog I've been assuming OP is German (and her name makes it likely), but valid point indeed.

Answer (score 9):

Other options:

- Leave the country and re-enter at some point. You may have to go further than Canada, Mexico, or the Caribbean to satisfy the VWP requirements, but if you can get cheap flight to South America it might be worth spending some time there.
- Depending on the flight times, baggage and airport opening hours, you might be able to go through security on the evening of day 90, and wait air side until your flight.

Comment: While airside, you're still in the USA so checking in early doesn't avoid the overstay.

Comment: The US doesn't do border control on exit, so you haven't left until the plane's departed

Comment: @pnuts Departed. As I recall, there is some leeway about unavoidable VWP overstays (e.g., if you were on life-support in hospital) but I'm not sure if "I planned to leave at the very last minute, but my plane was delayed" counts as unavoidable, since flights are delayed or cancelled all the time.

Comment: @DavidRicherby If it was cancelled and you couldn't be re-booked on a flight the same day, it'll usually be a valid excuse. For example if your flight was supposed to leave at 09:00AM on day 90, but you were re-booked on a flight at noon on day 91

Comment: @pnuts The airline staff sends a preliminary departure notice to the CBP upon check-in, and a final notice upon the actual departure, when it's clear that the passenger is onboard

Comment: @Taran would Cuba suffice?